# Best usage : Load product catalog feed

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I need for our website to load multiple product catalog from differente webstore.
Those are xml feed.
Usage will be: display products, look after stock line of a productId, search for product by name ...

What will be the best to load them ?

1/ PArse the xml and stock all product in a "huge table"
   1.1/ mysql
   2.2/ Nosql table

2/ Or stock them into xml file and digg into files each time i need to retrieve information about a product.

3/ there is a better a solution  !?

PS: we currently work under php and mysql

Thanks for answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data into a database, it will be much faster at retrieving it. And you generally need to retrieve the data more often than you need to store it.

Answer (score 0):

If these feeds don't change completely it will be good idea to add changes into mysql database and read them from there. it will be faster.